# Android Intent Filter - Regex match anything but

Tags: java, android, regex, intentfilter

Ok I know there is like 2000 posts like this, and I have viewed tons of them and their solutions before doing this, but I cannot for the life of me find a solution that works.

I want any example.com/xxxx link to ask to open my app, excluding /one and /two, my current IntentFilter successfully prevents one and two but doesn't do anything for /xyzabc (xxxx).

I've tried tons of Regex combos to no avail soo..what in my Regex/AndroidManifest is incorrect to cause this to happen?

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activities.ExampleViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_example_viewer"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:label="Example Viewer">
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/” -->
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="^(?!.*?(?:one|two)).*$"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="^(?!.*?(?:one|two)).*$"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="net.imperium.imperious.example.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I am aware the current Regex might not be too correct, it was the last one I tried after around 20 other failed attempts before it.

NOTE: I am not actually using example.com, it's only what it says, an example. The only thing actually different in my xml is the references to anything with "example".

ba ba bump

Comment: The documentation says that `The path part of a URI which must begin with a /`. Since your regex seems correct, did you try `/(?!.*?(?:one|two)).*$` ?

Comment: @maxoumime Tried it just now, still didn't work.

Comment: Your website is exposed in http right? No https?

Comment: @maxoumime It's not my website, but yes it's http.